# Rbind/Append two lists that contain data frames with same columns but different number of rows

Tags: r, list, append, rbind, mapply

List 1 contains for a number of stocks the HLC data (date, open price, close price, volume) up until date T. Each list component is a data frame with identical column names but the row length can vary depending on the history length for the stock.

List 2 is an update of List 1 with the latest data starting on date T+1

Please, let me know if there is an obvious solution to append "rbind(List1, List2)" without writing a for loop. I have searched the board tried mapply but no success so far. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need

```
Map(rbind, List1, List2)
```

Comment: Perfect, that does the job. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, I just had removed my last question on how to remove the last entry. I used lapply to solve it. Thanks also for your proposal.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  Is this what you want?

```
f <- function(i){
  rbind(List1[[i]],List2[[i]])
}

do.call("rbind",lapply(1:length(List1), f))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Your solution creates a flat data frame where the two lists are stacked. I need to keep the structure of List1 and only extend each entry with List2 elements